# Notation in $p$-adic integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, p-adic-number-theory

When we write $\mathbb{Z}_3$, does it mean $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$?  Also, does $3\mathbb{Z}_3$ mean $0 \pmod 3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Many* notations in mathematics are overloaded.  Whenever you are working in mathematics, it is very important to keep track of the *context* in which you are working.  For example, in the expression
$$ 3^s = 2 \implies s \in \left\{ \log_{3}(2) + i\frac{2\pi}{\log(3)} \right\},$$
they symbol $i$ (clearly?) represents the imaginary unit, i.e. the complex number which, when squared, gives $-1$.  On the other hand, in the notation
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \alpha^i = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}, $$
the variable $i$ is the index of summation.  In both cases, the notation should be unambiguous, as the context makes it clear what is going on.

Similarly, the notation $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is potentially ambiguous, but is typically clear with the correct context.  In the context of anything $p$-adic, the notation $\mathbb{Z}_3$ unambiguously represents the $3$-adic integers.  If you are working in a $p$-adic setting (or, more generally, if the words "local field" appear in your work), then it is safe to assume that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is the set of $3$-adic integers.  On the other hand, it is quite common to use $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to denote the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ in other contexts.  If you are not explicitly working in a setting where the $3$-adic integers might pop up, it is safe to assume that $\mathbb{Z}_3 = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.  If you fear that there is any *potential* for ambiguity, then make it clear—unambiguously define your notation.

With respect to the last part of your question, $3\mathbb{Z}_3$ almost certainly denotes the set
$$ 3\mathbb{Z}_3 = \{ 3x \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}_3 \}, $$
which is the ball of radius $\frac{1}{3}$ centered at zero in the space of $3$-adic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$\Bbb Z_n$ is a bit of an ambiguous notation without further context. I've seen it used both as a means of denoting the integers mod $n$, and as a means of denoting the $n$-adic integers - two very different things as you might imagine.

$\Bbb Z / n \Bbb Z$ however is less ambiguous from my experience: it denotes the quotient set of the integers mod the set of the integer multiples of $n$, i.e. it is the integers mod $n$. I've never seen it used to denote a $p$-adic entity.

So in a $p$-adic context you'll probably see the subscript notation when speaking of the $p$-adic integers and to avoid confusion in said context you should see the quotient set notation whenever modular arithmetic and such is relevant.

Comment: ok, we have $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Yeah I worded that poorly, since without specifying the operations it could be any number of algebraic objects. My bad. I think quotient set would be the proper term without specifying operations but I'll have to double-check, been a while.